# Can't get ResponsiveFileManager to work with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

When I click on the insert image button to upload an image I get this pop up error
[image: When I click on the insert image button to upload an image I get this pop up error]

```
    <script>tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 400,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview 
         anchor', 'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code '
        ],
        filemanager_crossdomain: true,


       external_filemanager_path:"responsive_filemanager/filemanager/",
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : 
        "/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft 
        aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent 
        indent | styleselect",
        toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image 
        media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
        image_advtab: true ,
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
    });</script>
```

Here is my script for the filemanager/TinyMCE, I havent touched the config.php file either. All I have done is downloaded the files and directed to my script to the correct path and it pulls the buttons for the filemanager in okay on TinyMCE but when I go to upload an image I get that error pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Open lfm.php. This is in the config folder if you're using Laravel. Change:
'base_directory' => 'public',
to the directory the filemanager is in. For example:
'base_directory' => '../another_directory',